# Setting HTML input as value to model then send it to view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am writing this booking system for an assignment, and the task is to do it in ASP.NET MVC.

I cannot figure out how to give a c# variable the value of an html input field type text and type select.

I have this:

```
<div class="controls">
    <label for="month"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Check-in Month</label>
    <select class="floatLabel" id="CheckInMonth">
        <option value="blank" selected disabled></option>
        <option value="01">January</option>
        <option value="02">February</option>
        <option value="03">March</option>
        <option value="04">April</option>
        <option value="05">May</option>
        <option value="06">June</option>
        <option value="07">July</option>
        <option value="08">August</option>
        <option value="09">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And this:

```
<div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="Name" class="floatLabel" name="name" placeholder="Name">
</div>
```

And I want to save the user typed input in a model and send it to a view when I press a button thereafter.

So I was wondering if anyone knew the answer to:

1. Is there a way to save the user input to a model, and still keep the the same css from the classes?
2. Is there a way to send that model to a view for use?

Comment: Did you take the asp.net MVC tutorial provided by Microsoft? It will show you the basics of binding your model to a view

Comment: Please go through this; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Comment: and this; Form tutorial, model binding https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-HtmlBeginForm-Tutorial-with-example.aspx

Comment: In the documentation i only see how to take a model to a view and not the other way around, but what i want is to take the variables the user types in, store it in a model, send that model to my controller, work with the variables i just stored in the model i just send to my controller and send a new view from my controller when im done working with the variables.

Comment: "what i want is to take the variables the user types in, store it in a model, send that model to my controller" ...that's what happens when you submit a form back to a controller action. The Microsoft tutorial covers this. This is the page which covers that aspect in most detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view

Comment: yeah, i have tried that, i have put a html "<form asp-controller..." around my user input and a button of type submit, but instead of actually submitting the form to my hard typed controller and then action, it just reloads the page.